# How to correctly create a query to get information from the PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql

How, with one request,
to get two records from table "Table" with id = 12 and id = 17 in PostgreSQL database?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a where in clause:

```
where id in (12,17);
```

Fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/696